# Stoping the iCloud attack

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud

I never thought I would say this but I am starting to hate this company.
In the past year I have an attack from Apple on my iCloud.

First I had the basic plan, then they bothered me everyday to **upgrade**, I did.
Now, I exceeded the amount of space , and this is what happens:

1. Every morning, my Mac starts with a message to **upgrade** the iCloud, and force me to go into a window to do so or manage my space. Leave my mac alone !
2. I get 2 emails a week from iCloud to **upgrade**, *without* subscription option.
3. I get messages on my iPhone to **upgrade** once a week.
4. I get message on my iPad twice a week to **upgrade**.

**How do I cancel these messages?**

Is it legal to garbage me everyday with these messages?

Comment: [Manage your iCloud storage](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204247): If you reach or exceed your iCloud storage limit, **learn how to manage your storage** and where you can buy more.

Comment: I've cleared out most of the comments. For further discussions please use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

To answer both of your questions:

> How do I cancel this attack?

and

> Is it legal to garbage me everyday with these messages?

**It's not an "attack" and it's perfectly legal since you agreed to it.**

Apple is fully within their rights to send you *communications* letting you know (generally speaking) the status of your account.

When you completed the service activation for your iCloud account, you electronically agreed to the Terms and Conditions (you know that "legal" box nobody reads and just reflexively says "yes" to just so they can continue on with the installation?) you gave Apple the *legal* authority to contact you about your service if/when you exceed your storage limit; which you did.

From the [iCloud Terms and Conditions](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/icloud/en/terms.html) page

> We may contact you via email regarding your account, for reasons
>   including, **without limitation, reaching or exceeding your storage
>   limit.**

(emphasis mine)

Right there, it says that if Apple wanted to send you an email every minute of every day, they could and would be legally indemnified from doing so because you agreed to this condition.

**Your options**

- Deactive your iCloud Account
- Buy more storage
- Delete some files

Short of that advice, there's no circumventing this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61298/discussion-on-answer-by-allan-why-is-apple-sending-me-icloud-upgrade-notices).